# Error when extending a Class in Java SE 6

Tags: java, constructor

Why does the Grade class which extends the School class give me an error when a new object is being created and the constructor is being called and passed the correct amount of parameters with the correct datatypes to the constructor?

I get the following warning in Netbeans using Java Se 6

> cannot find symbol: Constuctor School();

```
package school;

public class School {
    String name;
    String location;
    int pupils;

    School(String name, String location, int pupils) {
        this.name = name;
        this.location = location;
        this.pupils = pupils;
    }

}
```

---

```
package school;
public class Grade extends School {
    School school = new School("Your Schools Name", "Your schools Location", 1700);
}
```

Comment: On what earth does a Grade extend a School?

Comment: You also probably want to make the `School` constructor `public`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Constructors are not inherited. Your subclass needs its own constructor:

```
Grade(String name, String location, int pupils) {
    super(name, location, pupils);
}
```

Besides, this is very questionable design. A grade is not a school.

Comment: but shouldn't a grade inherit the Schools info if it is part of a school?

Comment: @Matthew grade can have a reference to school it belongs to.

Comment: @Matthew it's important to understand that inheritance means "is a": if you write `Grade extends School`, then that means that a `Grade` *is a* (specialized version of a) `School`. Don't misuse inheritance just because you need to access data from another class.

Comment: @MK I just want con confirm my understanding of inheritance so eg. MyHighShool extends School would be the correct use of inheritance?

Answer (score 4):

If a class, such as your Grade class, does not have an explicit constructor it will instead be given an implicit constructor which takes no arguments. An implicit constructor will invoke the no-argument constructor of the superclass. However, your superclass does not have a constructor with no arguments.

Answer (score 1):

The class `School` does not have default constructor `School()`. You have to create it in order to do the thing you want to do, although I do not really know why you would want to do it.

Answer (score 0):

The class School defines a constructor with arguments.  Because of that, compiler doesn't generate a default parameterless constructor for it.
In the class Grade you do not define any constructors.  So Java tries to generate a default constructor for it, but can't, because it has to call parent's default constructor (no arguments) and it doesn't exist. 
So you either need a default constructor in Grade which calls the existing constructor in School (with 3 args) or a default constructor in School.

Also your inheritance makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

Your subclass needs its own constructor as follows:

```
   Grade(String name, String location, int pupils)  
   {         
       super(name, location, pupils); 
   }
```